# Backbone views and subviews

Tags: backbone.js

I have a form which gets fields added dynamically when clicked on add field button. Now for that new field, i need to have a separate view as it has some functionality attached. I am aware that there is a concept of subviews.

My question is that when should i choose a subview over the view and should i in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly , check this fiddle i have created : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nishantjani10/4WgY4/)

This serves as an example for a separate view / sub view concept.

Now, building on the example and discussing the **sub view vs single view** option , if you see the example  , i create a **sub view** for each link i add , by doing this :

```
var listItem = new printView({ model: model}); //create a new view
$('#list').append(listItem.render().el);       //append that view to my main view
```

this helps me in a lot of ways :-

1. I have a view for each model
2. I can associate actions to each view and they take care of them individually
3. Modularity

If you go for **single view approach** , you face 1 problem upfront is , when i click or remove (any action which you define) on a particular element , **how do i get which model is it** ?

Solution for the above is , you can associate the cid with each element and when that element is clicked or removed (any action which you define) you can go a `getByCid()` to get the appropriate model.

Personally i would go with sub view or separate view approach since that gives a lot more **flexibility** and **readability** to your code.

Thank you.

Comment: thanks for your time. so subview is just a separate view called by some other view. M i right? Further i have seen statements in some views like this this.child{ var view=new someview()}. So what does that mean? Is it a method to declare a subview.

Comment: @beNerd , about the this.child{} part , im not quite aware ,sorry, but about using sub views , sure its a good practice , it just does good , if you like i can create the same example in a single view approach so you can compare maybe ?

Comment: please see the views in this:  http://kilon.org/blog/2012/08/build-backbone-apps-using-requirejs/ Hope you see, what i mean. See the master view.

Comment: @beNerd i really doubt if that approach is any different from what iv done , sorry to ask , but what exactly are you trying to do , when your not able to deceide whether to use single or sub view ? I d really advocate the use of sub view in any case

Comment: yes i will have subview in any case. I have seen its advantages in my recent project and i highly advocate the same. I just wanted to know that the method used in this.child... is some way of defining a subview or its just another way of creating views? Just need help of someone experienced like you get my fundas cleared. whats the advantage of using this.child method? and what does it mean.

Comment: @beNerd, alright , just to be on the same page , you actually mean this.children instead of this.child in the link you shared ? and particularly you are reffering to this code ? 

this.children = {
        taskList: new TaskList({collection: this.collection}),
        newTask: new NewTask({collection: this.collection}),
        markAll: new MarkAll({collection: this.collection}),
        footerView: new FooterView({collection: this.collection})
      }; ??

Comment: yes. why use this.children under the initialization and then referring to these views as this.children.someview. Why don't just initialize these views directly as you did.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24306/discussion-between-user1537158-and-benerd)